# How convert Bag to fields in pig

Tags: apache-pig, databags

I Have a data coming from UDF as bag 
Output:({(http://www.myurl.com 1000 1000)})
How do I generate 3 different fields from this bag as url, height,width.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flatten](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Flatten+Operator) operator,

```
GENERATE flatten ({(http://www.myurl.com 1000 1000)}) as myTuple
```

will gives this tuple :

```
(http://www.myurl.com 1000 1000)
```

And to get 3 tuples we need [STRSPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#strsplit):

```
STRSPLIT(myTuple,' ',3))as(url:chararray,height:chararray,width:chararray)
```